# Emacs company-bootstrap (how to make it auto active in web-mode)?

Tags: bootstrap-4, emacs

When in web-mode while editing a html file, I've to hit **M-x company-bootstrap** to see a list of possible value for a class in a html tag.

```
<p class="M-X company-bootstrap here ..">
```

Is it possible to make it auto active while opening a html file.  I'm faced the same issue with **company-web-html**.

I defined in my configuration file that :

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (
 lambda()
   (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends) '(company-css company-web-html company-yasnippet company-files company-bootstrap))
   (company-mode t)))
```

But not working.

Thk for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `company-backends` before using:

```lisp
(require 'company)     ; Import company-backends variable
(require 'company-web) ; Import required backends
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-css)
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-web-html)
```

Activate `company-mode` globally or only for `web-mode`:

```lisp
(global-company-mode 1) ; Global company-mode.
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'company-mode) ; Run only for web-mode.
```